# How to update components of a JPanel if some action is performed in another JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to update a `JPanel` if some action is performed in another `JPanel`.

**Example:**
A `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` contains the following:

1.) Class `LabelPanel` which extends `JPanel` and contains a `JLabel` that displays a value
 2.) Class `ButtonPanel` which extends `JPanel` and contains a `JButton`

If the user clicks the `JButton`, the value of the `JLabel` should be increased by 50 .

The `JLabel` should somehow be called by an `ActionListener` listening to the `JButton`. How could you do that?

MainPanel:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
   public MainPanel() {
      this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      this.add(new LabelPanel());
      this.add(new ButtonPanel());

   }
}
```

LabelPanel:

```
public class LabelPanel extends JPanel {
   public LabelPanel() {
      this.add(new JLabel("Value: " + 0));
   }
}
```

ButtonPanel:

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {
   public ButtonPanel() {
      this.add(new JButton());
   }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely nothing stops you from doing that. You add the ActionListener to the button, and have it update the label. Whether or not it is in a different panel is immaterial.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question so that it reflects my problem better. The JPanels are in seperate class files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer isn't difficult. Lets say your `JButton` is called `button` and your `JLabel` is called `label`, you can do something like this:

```
button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> // register ActionListener
{
    int value = Integer.parseInt(label.getText()); // get current value of the label
    value += 50; // increase value by 50
    label.setText(Integer.toString(value)); // update text of the label
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the following,

> private TextField tfCount;  // declare component TextField
>   private Button btnCount;    // declare component Button
>   private int count = 0;      // counter's value

```
btnCount = new Button("Count");     // allocate Button instance
add(btnCount);                     // "this" Frame adds btnCount
btnCount.addActionListener(this);

 // ActionEvent handler - Called back when the button has been clicked.
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      count = Integer.parseInt(tfInput.getText());
      count += 50;                     // incrase the counter value
      tfCount.setText(count + ""); // display on the TextField
                                   // setText() takes a String
   }
```